# TFS power tool shell extention icon overlay appear on files/folders not under source control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, shell-extensions

I'm running Windows XP Professional SP3, with Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I installed the latest version of TFS power tool lately. Just now I found out that the icon overlay of the shell extension appear over ALL the files/folders inside the mapped folder of my team project, including those not under source control, such as log files, bin, debug, release folders etc..

When I right click those folder, I can see the TFS context menus. But when I tried to view the history, it shows an error message saying that the item "could not be found in your workspace, or you don't have the right to access it."

I used another PC which is connected to the same TFS server. I mapped the same team project to a local folder. There is no problem with the shell extension icon overlay. Those files/folders not under source control are shown without the TFS overlay.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially more mappings pointing to your local system from source control than you recognize. For a **hard reset of your workspaces** perform the following steps:

1. Make sure all local changes you want to keep are checked in
2. Remove all workspaces that mapping to your local system (make sure that is performed for any user on that client system if there are multiple users)
3. Remove the mapped folders and their content physically from disk
4. Make a new mapping from source control to a new physical folder
5. Get latest version of your source code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I followed exactly the steps you provided. Remove all workspaces, remove content physically, make a new mapping, then get latest. The problem still remains. One thing I tried further showcase the problem. In windows explorer, inside one of the TFS source controlled folder I manually created a new txt file, once I hit enter, immediately there is a overlay on the icon.

Comment: That icon that appears, is that an icon with a plus-sign in it (the add to source-control icon)?

Comment: No. It remains as the "Controlled" icon (the simple green triangle without anything on it) no matter what I do. I tried checking out, as well as adding it to TFS. The icon never change.